# How can I create an external switch but refrain to use the external dhcp in Hyper V?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2012

The requirement might seem strange. I have an organisational network (external network), but I desire to create a own private network of VMs in Hyper-v with its own domain and DHCP server(which runs in a VM). I do not want to use the IPs supplied by the external DHCP as the pool is limited.Moreover, I want these private IPs to be accessible from a machine in the external network.

To simplify, I want to access a 192.168.x.x range of IP (which the vm DHCP assigns to the individual VMs) from 10.x.x.x network(ext network), but I do not want the virtual DHCP server to interfere in the external network. With my efforts so far , I have not been able to find a solution to this.

Can this be done ?
If not , how are VMs which are in a "internal" or "private" network supposed to be used in Hyper-V , is it by accessing the host machine all the time? This does not seem convenient.